# Suspend killed my laptop (can't resume, can't reboot, no BIOS screen)

Tags: 12.04, suspend

I just got a Toshiba Satellite C675D-S7109 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) on it.  I installed all the updates as well but didn't install the fglrx drivers.  Seemed like it was working fine.

I suspended the laptop.  Whoops, now it's a brick.  No key, mouse button, or power button would resume it.  The fan was still running and both power LEDs were on (one indicating the laptop is plugged in, one indicating it's powered on).

I held down the power button for 8s to force it to power off.  Fan goes off, HD spins down, power light goes out, all as expected.

When I hit the power button to turn it back on, fan comes on, HD spins up, but it doesn't show the BIOS splash screen or anything -- just a totally black screen, like before I powered it off.

**Edit:** I removed the battery for a while and now it boots normally.  Should I just disable suspend or is there a way around this?

**Edit2:** I tried `sudo pm-hibernate` -- it didn't shut down the laptop but after forcing power off and powering back on it resumed just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and replacing the battery un-bricks the laptop, so that's a workaround at least.  I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1000016

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but essentially it only kills the screen.

You can check yourself: type "sudo pm-suspend" from the prompt. i assume it works (here it works). this is the same command as called when you close your lid.

Now open a terminal and already type "sudo pm-suspend". do not press enter.

now close the lid. your computer becomes what you call "a brick".

now press enter (which will execute the command you just typed in the command line). maybe you also need to type your root password followed by another enter.

voila, your computer went into suspend and resumes when you open the lid.

Comment: What kind of laptop do you have?  In my case, pm-suspend bricks the laptop and I have to force power off, remove power cord and battery, and start back up.  It's definitely killing more than the screen -- pings from another machine cease shortly after pm-suspend is run.